# generating mean values to empty cells

Tags: spss

I am new to SPSS and I am trying to generate average values to empty cells (basically fill in missing info by the average answer the user has given) and I cannot get my example code to work (or understand the example well).

```
COMPUTE QOL_puutt = Nmiss(ass, bass, grass, gas).
```

This part I understand

```
Do repeat A  = ass1 ass2  ass3. If ((Missing (A)) & QOL_puutt <= 4) A
= RND(Mean (ass1, ass2, ass3)).  End repeat.
```

Here something goes wrong. I understood that ass1,ass2,ass3 would refer to cells (column ass row 3)??? Here are the error codes

```
Error # 4285 in column 15. Text: ass1 Incorrect variable name: either the name is more than 64 characters, or it is not defined by a previous command. Execution of this command stops.

Error # 4285 in column 15. Text: ass2 Incorrect variable name: either the name is more than 64 characters, or it is not defined by a previous command. Execution of this command stops.

Error # 4285 in column 15. Text: ass3 Incorrect variable name: either the name is more than 64 characters, or it is not defined by a previous command. Execution of this command stops
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a little hard to tell what the code is due to the wrapping, but you can simplify it like this
do repeatA = ass1 ass2 ass3.
if missing(A) A = mean(ass, bass, grass, gas).
end repeat.

If all the values are missing, mean will return sysmis automatically.
If you want to require a certain number of nonmissing values, say, 2,
you could write the statement as
if missing(A) A = mean.2(ass, bass, grass, gas).

HTH,
Jon Peck